# Why can't PyPDF2 find all occurrences of words read from a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I am trying to build a book index for which I am reading keywords from a CSV table in Python 3. I iterate through all pages in a PDF file (read as string) to find the keywords (strings) and collect the page numbers of their occurrences in a dictionary of lists. The keywords ingested serve as keys.

The script is a bit long, so I put it on [GITHUB](https://github.com/MonikaBarget/DigitalHistory/blob/master/FindKEYWORDSinPDF_PyPDF2.py) for you to check.

It is certainly not the leanest solution possible, but it is working OK... EXCEPT:

it only captures about half of the instances where the keywords actually occur.

Searching for the first word in my keyword table, "abolition", I got five or so page numbers but should have gotten about ten. The page numbers the script found were all correct --- just not complete.

I am wondering if this is either

- a mistake I make in reading or writing my data
- a problem with the original PDF file
  or
- a problem with the PyPDF2 package I am using to read the PDF file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PyPDF2`, I have now tried `PDFtoText` and the results are much more reliable:

`TRYING TO FIND abolition : WORD FOUND: abolition on page 13 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 290 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 291 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 298 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 299 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 300 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 301 WORD FOUND: abolition on page 309 WORD FOUND: Abolition on page 310 TRYING TO FIND abolitionist : WORD FOUND: abolitionist on page 290 WORD FOUND: abolitionist on page 298 WORD FOUND: abolitionist on page 299 WORD FOUND: abolitionist on page 301 TRYING TO FIND Leibniz : WORD FOUND: Leibniz on page 182 TRYING TO FIND Clara : WORD FOUND: Clara on page 182 Done`

However, I have no explanation why one package outperforms the other.